# Using footnotes with \par in eledmac's paragraphed footnotes

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs, eledmac

I was asked to do some adoptions to the footnote layout using eledmac. One request I could not implement so far is to combine the "footparagraph" option with a long footnote containing paragraphs itself (and/or line breaks).

eledmac offers the `parapparatus` option for "normal" critical footnotes. However, I am looking explicitly for paragraphed familiar footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[parapparatus]{eledmac} % Option only for "normal" footnotes
\footparagraphX{A}

\begin{document}
   Test\footnoteA{A test footnote with a\par new paragraph in it.}
\end{document}
```

I read through the source code of eledmac and tried to modify some routines, e.g. `\newcommand*`->`\newcommand`, but I did not succeed.

Does anyone of you have an idea how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is now way to do it, because eledmac paragraphed footnote create hboxes, which can't contain parbreak. Indeed, that is a non sense.

Comment: Thank you Maïeul for your comment. As I said I was asked to present a solution, although I as well stated that combining those two is not a good idea.

Anyway, I think I will implement something using different series. That won't be perfect, but good enough.

Comment: Have you resolved it?